# Can I like photos of people who aren't my friends?

Tags: facebook

If I am not friends with a person on Facebook but can see their photos, can I "like" a photo?

Comment: It depends on their privacy settings.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it depends on their privacy settings, whether it is posted as "Public" or "Friends" or *Some Customized list*. It is just that if you see "Like" button, you can; if not, you cannot, and same goes for "Comment" and "Share" options.